# JQuery: insert one image several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert

I don't think it's a new problem. But for me it's a new.

```
var image = new Image;

image.src = 'https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo11w.png';

$('div#imagePlace').append(image);
$('div#imagePlace').append(image);
$('div#imagePlace').append(image);
```

But inserted only one image. How inserted needed number of images without numerous downloads of the same image.

Comment: If you insert an image one time, every other appearance of the same image will not be downloaded :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct an `<img>` object, and in a for loop, clone it and append to your element of interest:

```
$(function() {
    var $img = $('<img />', {
        'src': 'http://placehold.it/100x100'
    });

    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        $img.clone().appendTo('#imagePlace');
    }
});
```

If you don't [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the jQuery object, you will end up moving it instead of making copies of it.

See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/Lmvnunq9/